# Configuring CORS in Felix's HTTPService (backed with Jetty)

Tags: java, cross-domain, jetty, apache-felix, httpserver

I'm running a felix container with HttpService implemented by Jetty.

Jetty supports CORS using the Cross-Origin-Filter and it's usually configured in web.xml as seen e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303162/jetty-cross-origin-filter)

Unfortunately, the Felix HTTPService doesn't expose anything of the sort [as far as I can tell](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html), so the question is: how do I get that configuration to my "felix wrapped" Jetty?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to break through the Felix barrier to programmatically configure Cross-Origin-Filters, *but* a possible workaround, if very simple filters are needed, is to manually add the required fields, as in:

```
resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```