# adobe connect cross-origin filter

Tags: adobe, cross-domain, jetty, adobe-connect

I am creating a web app that checks the status of other sites and services.  One page checks whether other sites are up on other domains.  Most sites are using IIS7, so I just have to add an http response header to allow access from the domain hosting my page:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *
```

My problem is that one thing I have to check is whether the adobe connect server is up, and it uses Jetty.  I looked at these two pages:

- [Jetty Cross Origin Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303162/jetty-cross-origin-filter)
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter

I download the `jetty-servlet.jar`, put it in my `E:\Breeze\8.2.0.1\appserv\web\WEB-INF\lib` folder, and add the following lines in my `E:\Breeze\8.2.0.1\appserv\web\WEB-INF\web.xml`  file:

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>//*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

but when I do, I get a 404 The requested resource () is not available when I try to reach the site in a web browser.

I'm using java version 1.6 and I've tried every version of the `jetty-serlet.jar` listed on the site above.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, the standard Connect install uses Tomcat, not Jetty. (Unless you've chosen to run CPS on Jetty.) But I think the CrossOriginFilter works in Tomcat as well.

Why the extra slash in the url-pattern? Wouldn't you want:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Is there any trace of your request in the container or CPS logs?