# Set web server headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) in web-app running under jetty-runner

Tags: jetty, cors, plantuml

I'm running the [plantuml.war](http://www.plantuml.com/server.html) on a server using [jetty-runner](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/runner.html). I need to enable the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for CORS, but the way I found to do this points to a [web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303162/jetty-cross-origin-filter) or an [override-web.xml](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/override-web-xml.html), which I think are out of my control because I'm using a third-party web-app in jetty-runner. I can't see a way to set this up in jetty.xml.

Is there a way to enable the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header inside of jetty-runner?

Comment: Having `jetty-runner` as a requirement will make this difficult to fix.  Your level of configuration requirement means you should graduate to a full `jetty-distribution` instead.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I got something to work with only adding `jetty-servlets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I got help with the details on this (not my answer 100%). I tested it only under Windows 7 and Windows 8 with Java 7.

In addition to `jetty-runner.jar`, one needs also `jetty-servlets.jar`.

Add a file `override-web.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">

<filter>
  <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
      <param-value>origin, content-type, accept, authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Then make a `jetty-web.xml` context

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="war">/</Set>
  <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/override-web.xml</Set>
</Configure>
```

Run PlantUML's server as follows

```
java -jar jetty-runner.jar --config jetty.xml --jar jetty-servlets.jar plantuml.war jetty-web.xml
```